# SBS 2008 Backup continuation

Tags: windows-sbs-2008

My SBS 2008 server's external 1TB backup drive (USB) is 70% filled. I have done the a full backup on day 1 and have elected an "incremental" backup for the default configuration of backing up 2x everyday. I have two questions: (1) Does SBS Backup do a full backup on its own? When? and (2) What happens if my 1TB drive gets full? Do I just put in a fresh 1TB backup drive and mark it as a backup volume and SBS will continue to do incremental backups with the ocassional full backup? or should I do a FULL backup with the new drive and then incrementally as I did on my 1st backup drive?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Incremental backups simply add files or remove files or apply changes to pre-existing files from an original backup. If this drive gets full (assuming it's only backup) then just take it out, pop in a new one, full backup, then do incremental.

Comment: I already know this. I've already read the SBS 2008 backup technical documents on Technet. What I'm asking for is do I "continue" the incremental backup to another drive if backup1 gets full? Is that even possible or more importantly, a best practice?

Comment: No, it's not a good idea at all. What if the first drive fails? Then you're left with changes and no source.